# Select a message based ont its subject from Outlook 2010, and run a macro that will copy data to Excel without manual intervention

Tags: vba, outlook

Regretfully I have no formal background in VBA, but I have been able to learn quite a bit from sites like this.

Problem Statement:

I have a few emails with contain information that needs to be stored in excel.  Fortunately I do have working script for that. Not provided to keep this somewhat shorter

The problem that I am facing is that capturing the right email from Microsoft Outlook 2010 and storing the data WITHOUT manual intervention.
The Email will contain a specific word/phrase, "EVEREST".  Obviously it is not the only email received. It contains no attachments, and will come from various senders.
I have tried various macros I have found on-line to pull the message from the inbox, but none of them have worked for me.
So I have a macros that will pull messages from a personal folder, that macro then runs another macros that stores the contents of the email to excel, then it moves the message to its final resting place (another personal Folder) currently they all work fine together, but require manual intervention to complete the task.   After the message is moved to the personal folder I simply click on a Quick Access Toolboar Icon mapped to a macro

To get the message moved over the personal folder i have a rule set up to move the message based on the word "EVEREST" and runs the initial script.
The problem with all of this is that the message will get moved to the folder, but needs manual intervention to complete the task. I would like it to run automatically.

I have been fumbling around with this for the past 2 months and seem to be in a stalemate.   I would greatly appreciate your feedback and assistance.

The following is what I have so far.

My outlook rule set is:

Apply this rule after the message arrives
with "EVEREST" in the subject
and on this computer only
move it to the "EVEREST PRI" folder
and run "Project1.ThisOutlookSession.Everest"

```
' I believe these were put here when I was trying to run         '
' everything via VBA macros, vice using the rule set above       '

CLass Module (1)
Option Explicit
Private WithEvents Items As Outlook.Items
Private WithEvents olInboxItems As Items




'  ThisOutlookSession contains the following scripts         '

'This is the script that is run from the outlook rules       '
' all it does is calls the "OCF" Sub below                   '
Sub Everest(email As MailItem)
OCF
End Sub

'This scipt opens the "EVEREST PRI" personal sub folder'
' and calls the "Prepwork" sub below                   '
Sub OCF()
Dim objOlApp As Outlook.Application
Dim Ns As Outlook.NameSpace
Dim objFolder As Outlook.Folder
Dim EmailCount As Integer

   Set objOlApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
   Set Ns = Session.Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")
   Set objFolder = Ns.Folders("Personal Folders").Folders("Archives").Folders("EVEREST PRI")
   Set objOlApp.ActiveExplorer.CurrentFolder = objFolder

   Set objFolder = Nothing
   Set objOlApp = Nothing
Prepwork
End Sub

'I had hoped that the following routine would do the rest of the work     '
'but it doesn't do it all the time. Most the time the message hasn't been '
'moved to the personal folder before its kicked off.                      '
'So I thought I would call another macro to play catch up  "Wait" below   '
Sub Prepwork()
Dim objOlApp As Outlook.Application
Dim Ns As Outlook.NameSpace
Dim objFolder As Outlook.Folder
Dim EmailCount As Integer

 Set objOlApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
 Set Ns = Session.Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")
 Set objFolder = Ns.Folders("Personal Folders").Folders("Archives").Folders("EVEREST PRI")
 Set objOlApp.ActiveExplorer.CurrentFolder = objFolder

 EmailCount = objFolder.Items.count
  If EmailCount = 1 Then
   'MsgBox "A COMSPOT has been recieved, acknowledge to update the chart'
' I tried adding this msgbox to provide some time delay,  although  '
' it has worked from time to time, it still requires manual         '
' intervention, which is not desired.                               '
   CopyToExcel
' CopyToExcel is the macro that writes my information to the        '
' Spreadsheet.  This script has been flawless and I have created    '
' a Clickable ICON in the Quick Access Toolboar.                    '
  ElseIf EmailCount = 0 Then
 Wait
End If
End Sub



'The following "Wait Script was added, hoping to give time for the other   '
'macros to finish, but i suspect they are all linked together, and wont    '
'finish until all macroshave finished including the previously mentioned   '
' "CopyToExcel" macro.                                                    '
' I have also tried to run this macro from the outlook rules,  no joy......'
Sub Wait() '(email As MailItem)
' this provides a 5 second wait'
Sleep (5000)
Dim objOlApp As Outlook.Application
Dim Ns As Outlook.NameSpace
Dim objFolder As Outlook.Folder
Dim EmailCount As Integer

 Set objOlApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
 Set Ns = Session.Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")
 Set objFolder = Ns.Folders("Personal Folders").Folders("Archives").Folders("EVEREST PRI")
 Set objOlApp.ActiveExplorer.CurrentFolder = objFolder

  EmailCount = objFolder.Items.count
   If EmailCount = 1 Then
   'MsgBox "A COMSPOT has been recieved, acknowledge to update the chart"
  CopyToExcel
   ElseIf EmailCount = 0 Then
   ' MsgBox "The second Marco (Wait) did not locate a Message in the PRI Folder.  Run the script from the Quick Access Toolboar"
   End If
End Sub


 ' The following macro moves each of the selected items on the screen to an'
 ' Archive folder.   I have not had any problems with this macro           '
 ' This macro is called from the "CopyToExcel" macro. (not shown as it     '
 ' has also worked fine since incorporating it                             '
Sub ArchiveItems() ' Moves each of the selected items on the screen to an Archive folder.
Dim olApp As New Outlook.Application
Dim olExp As Outlook.Explorer
Dim olSel As Outlook.Selection
Dim olNameSpace As Outlook.NameSpace
Dim olArchive As Outlook.Folder
Dim intItem As Integer

 Set olExp = olApp.ActiveExplorer
 Set olSel = olExp.Selection
 Set olNameSpace = olApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
' This assumes that you have an Inbox subfolder named Archive.
 Set olArchive = olNameSpace.Folders("Personal Folders").Folders("Archives").Folders("EVEREST Archive")

    For intItem = 1 To olSel.count
        olSel.Item(intItem).Move olArchive
    Next intItem
OIB
End Sub


' The following macro simply returns the view to the inbox folder,        '
' Thus returning everything to Normal                                     '
' The Ideal of returning to which every folder, or message was open at    '
' the time the EVEREST message first arrived I thought would be to        '
' complicated, but if any body could solve that... AMAZING....            '
Sub OIB()
Dim objOlApp As Outlook.Application
Dim Ns As Outlook.NameSpace
Dim objFolder As Outlook.Folder


 Set objOlApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
 Set objFolder = Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
 Set objOlApp.ActiveExplorer.CurrentFolder = objFolder

 Set objFolder = Nothing
 Set objOlApp = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: `Sub Everest(email As MailItem)` here `email` is the message you want to process - you should be able work directly with that.

Comment: Tim,    Its working like a dream.  I placed the macro I used to send my data to excel in the  copytoexcelwithperimeter macro.   Righteous, Brilliant.    Thank you so very much.

Comment: Tim Williams,    The macro your provided worked perfectly on this machine, which has been my test bed.  I have moved (copy and paste) the same macro to another machine running the same programs on a private network. I have verified the folders, but it will not run automatically.   Obviously I must be overlooking something, but I haven't been able to locate it yet,  Any help, words of wisdom, that will point me  back on track.

Comment: Sorry - I'm not a big Outlook programmer...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need to select, you already have the required "email" passed as a parameter by the rule.

The run a script code will look something like this.

```
Sub Everest(email As MailItem)
    Dim Ns As NameSpace
    'Dim inboxFolder As Folder
    Dim olArchive As Folder

    Set Ns = GetNamespace("MAPI")

    CopyToExcelWithParameter email

    'ArchiveItems
    Set olArchive = Ns.Folders("Personal Folders")
    Set olArchive = olArchive.Folders("Archives")
    Set olArchive = olArchive.Folders("EVEREST Archive")
    email.Move olArchive

    ' Edit: Just realized this was due to
    ' unnecessary folder selecting that is now gone
    ' This is unnecessary now as well
    'OIB
    'Set inboxFolder = Ns.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
    'Set ActiveExplorer.CurrentFolder = inboxFolder

    Set Ns = Nothing
    Set olArchive = Nothing
    'Set inboxFolder = Nothing

End Sub
```

You will have to rewrite CopyToExcel to take email as a parameter

```
Sub CopyToExcelWithParameter (email as mailitem)
    ' code that processes "email" directly, not a selection
    Debug.Print "Do something with " & email.subject
End Sub
```